# Fetch a value from KV store, but its not a Key:Value pair in the template

Tags: consul-template, consul-kv

All,
Is it possible to convert my server.cert.template file in to server.cert using consul template and consul KV.

In my Consul am defining a KV pair as follows:

```
    SERVER_SSL_CERT = 4r4ffqh;fhq2fhwhhqwpihpvhqv'in3v3rvnrqpnrvnnvvqn
```

And my server.cert.template looks as follows:

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    ${SERVER_SSL_CERT}
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Earlier I was using local files for this substitution. Can consul handle this and if so how ? How do I query consul to dump this value here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working as follows. Sharing it in case some one comes across a similar situation. Contents of my template file are as follows:

```
    {{$host := "hostname" -}}
    {{$keyname := printf "Project/%s/Certs/SERVER_SSL_CERT" $host -}}
    {{ key $keyname }}
```

When we run consul-template on it, it will print the value as part of the last line.